# A few questions about the winding number.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $C_a$ be a circle in the anti-clockwise direction around point $a$ in $\Bbb{C}$. If $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ is a continuous mapping, then $f(C_a)$ is the image of $C_a$ in $\Bbb{C}$. I have a few questions regarding $f(C_a)$. Kindly note that $f$ is merely a continuous mapping from $\Bbb{R^2}\to\Bbb{R^2}$, and may **not** be analytic.

1. If $C_a$ can be continuously deformed into $C'_a$ without crossing $a$, then is $v[f(C_a),f(a)]=v[f(C'_a),f(a)]$? Here $v[f(C_a),f(a)]$ is the winding number of $f(C_a)$ around $f(a)$.
2. How is $v[f(C_a),f(a)]$ generally determined if $f$ is not analytic? In the case of analytic mappings, we know that there is a deep relation between winding number and multiplicity. Is winding number completely arbitrary for a continuous mapping?

Answer (score 0):

The loop is a continuous map $C_a: \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{a \}$. Same for $C'_a$. Now a deformation between the two curves is a contunuous mapping $H:\mathbb{S}^1 \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{a \}$. But then $f \circ H$ is a deformation between the image curves. One now has to make sure that $f(a)$ is not in the image of $f \circ H$ in order for this to work: This is an important assumption, what if $a=0$ and $f(z)=Re(z)$ ? Then the image loops may actually intersect the point $f(a)$. So a good assumption is perhaps that $f(\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ a \} ) \subset \mathbb{C} \setminus \{a \}$.

Winding numbers can be defined without analyticity; it is purely topological using the idea of a fundamental group. Basically, it turns out that each loop on the punctured plane $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is homotopy equivalent (i.e: There exists a deformation) to a standard loop $z \mapsto z^n$ for some unique $n$, which is the winding number.